# How do I avoid ansible deployment failures due to dpkg lock file?

Tags: ansible

It seems that getting failures due to /var/lib/dpkg/lock is something not very rare. Based on observations these are caused most of the time 9/10 due to state lock file or while a cron job was running.

This means that a retry mechanism combined with a removal of stale file could be the solution.

How can I do this in ansible?

Comment: I dont think you can do loops in ansible. You could try the `wait_for` module to wait for the lock file to disappear and then run your apt.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/sfxonline/vagrant-shopware/blob/Ubuntu1604/ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml#L4) "Wait for automatic system updates" example. @user2599522, please see this [relevant issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/4241) using `wait_for` that way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd try to solve this with `until` feature of ansible (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops)

```
- name: Apt for sure
  apt: name=foobar state=installed
  register: apt_status
  # 2018 syntax:
  # until: apt_status|success
  # 2020 syntax:
  until: apt_status is success
  delay: 6
  retries: 10
```

Comment: doesn't work: `FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'apt_status|success' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'success'. String: {% if apt_status|success %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}`

Comment: It was Ansible 2018, and now it's 2020. `apt_status is success`.

Comment: Seems to no longer work with 2024 ansible: `{"msg": "The conditional check 'apt_status is success' failed. The error was: The 'failed' test expects a dictionary"}`

Comment: There is no 2024 Ansible. In ansible-core 2.16 it is working. You may have other problems with inventory, but simple is success is still working in case of apt module failing.